# Show just some variables in a list view

Tags: android, listview

I coded a ListView in Android using the simple adapater. 
I each item I show various numbers. 
I would like to show just the numbers diverse by 0.

So, for example, in the first row there are 3 numbers (all diverse by 0), all to get showed. 
In the second on, I just want to display one of them.

I think what I would like to realize is a dynamic list view where "elements" are loaded into if they just respect a condition. 
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand "diverse by 0", could you provide a simple example of what you want?

Comment: Please describe the problem in details. Do you want to dynamically change listview items? Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                    String textRepresentation) {
                  if(view.getId()==R.id.your_field){
                    Double field = Double.parseDouble((String) data.toString());
                    if(!field.equals(0.00)){
                        ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        ((TextView) view).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        return true;
                    }
                }return false;
            }
        } );
```

You could just set the text color you want to hide the same as the background. 
note: Using this code you've to use SimpleAdapter to make your ListView.